# How to split column data and create new DataFrame with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to split the data in the following DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'per': np.repeat([10,20,30], 32), 'r':12*range(8), 'cnt': np.random.randint(300, 400, 96)}); df

    cnt  per  r
0   355   10  0
1   359   10  1
2   347   10  2
3   390   10  3
4   304   10  4
5   306   10  5
..  ...  ... ..
87  357   30  7
88  371   30  0
89  396   30  1
90  357   30  2
91  353   30  3
92  306   30  4
93  301   30  5
94  329   30  6
95  312   30  7

[96 rows x 3 columns]
```

such that for each `r` value a new column `cnt_r{r}` exist in a DataFrame but also keeping the corresponding `per` column.

The following piece of code almost does what I want except that it *looses* the `per` column:

```
pd.DataFrame({'cnt_r{}'.format(i): df[df.r==i].reset_index()['cnt'] for i in range(8)})

   cnt_r0  cnt_r1  cnt_r2  cnt_r3  cnt_r4  cnt_r5  cnt_r6  cnt_r7
0     355     359     347     390     304     306     366     310
1     394     331     384     312     380     350     318     396
2     340     336     360     389     352     370     353     319
...
9      341     300     386     334     386     314     358     326
10     357     386     311     382     356     339     375     357
11     371     396     357     353     306     301     329     312
```

I need a way to build the follow DataFrame:

```
   per  cnt_r0  cnt_r1  cnt_r2  cnt_r3  cnt_r4  cnt_r5  cnt_r6  cnt_r7
0   10     355     359     347     390     304     306     366     310
1   10     394     331     384     312     380     350     318     396
2   10     340     336     360     389     352     370     353     319
...
7   20     384     385     376     323     345     339     339     347
9   30     341     300     386     334     386     314     358     326
10  30     357     386     311     382     356     339     375     357
11  30     371     396     357     353     306     301     329     312
```

Note that by construction my dataset has same number of values per `per` for each `r`. Obviously my dataset is much larger than the example one (about 800 million records).

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible use `reshape` for `2d array` and then [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new colum `per`:

```
np.random.seed(1256)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'per': np.repeat([10,20,30], 32), 
                        'r': 12*list(range(8)), 
                        'cnt': np.random.randint(300, 400, 96)})


df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['cnt'].values.reshape(-1, 8)).add_prefix('cnt_r')
df1.insert(0, 'per', np.repeat([10,20,30], 4))
print (df1)
    per  cnt_r0  cnt_r1  cnt_r2  cnt_r3  cnt_r4  cnt_r5  cnt_r6  cnt_r7
0    10     365     358     305     311     393     343     340     313
1    10     393     319     358     351     322     387     316     359
2    10     360     301     337     333     322     337     393     396
3    10     320     344     325     310     338     381     314     339
4    20     323     305     342     340     343     319     332     371
5    20     398     308     350     320     340     319     305     369
6    20     344     340     345     332     373     334     304     331
7    20     323     349     301     334     344     374     300     336
8    30     357     375     396     354     309     391     304     334
9    30     311     395     372     359     370     342     351     330
10   30     378     302     306     341     308     392     387     332
11   30     350     373     316     376     338     351     398     304
```

Or use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for create new groups and reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index([df.groupby('r').cumcount(), 'per','r'])['cnt']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('cnt_r')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
    per  cnt_r0  cnt_r1  cnt_r2  cnt_r3  cnt_r4  cnt_r5  cnt_r6  cnt_r7
0    10     365     358     305     311     393     343     340     313
1    10     393     319     358     351     322     387     316     359
2    10     360     301     337     333     322     337     393     396
3    10     320     344     325     310     338     381     314     339
4    20     323     305     342     340     343     319     332     371
5    20     398     308     350     320     340     319     305     369
6    20     344     340     345     332     373     334     304     331
7    20     323     349     301     334     344     374     300     336
8    30     357     375     396     354     309     391     304     334
9    30     311     395     372     359     370     342     351     330
10   30     378     302     306     341     308     392     387     332
11   30     350     373     316     376     338     351     398     304
```

Comment: Thank you some much for the enlightening answers! The problem I faced (on my dataset) with the first answer is with the insert. I had to create the `per` column with the following code 

   `df1.insert(0, 'per', df['per'].values.reshape(-1,8).transpose()[0])`

Otherwise the second solution works like a charm.

Comment: @Claudio - Hmmm, it depends of real data, `np.repeat` is not possible use?

Comment: you are too fast... :D

Comment: @Claudio - OK, I can check first solution

Comment: hmmm, for me your code and similar working `df1.insert(0, 'per', df['per'].values.reshape(-1,8)[:, [0]])`

Comment: blows my mind, I guess I need to dig a bit more into numpy arrays... Thanks so much!